# inet_pton does not work on local ip addresses like 10.0.1.4

Tags: php

```
<?php
//$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipaddress = '10.0.1.4';
$binip = inet_pton($ipaddress);
echo $binip;
?>
```

It returns blank. If i use my public facing IP it returns the right result. It will return a result for `192.168.1.2`(My old LinkSys router had a ip similar to this). I'm testing my app on a Linux machine i have with a local ip. All Machines that connect to it uses a internal ip `10.0.1.XX`. My app uses MySQL and if the binip is blank, it gives me a error. So i am not sure of a work around for local ip. I was thinking maybe it has to do with detecting if its a local ip in that format and then edit the ipaddress variable so its valid for inet_pton some how. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your problem with inet_ntop() as the title says, or with inet_pton() as the code sample shows, or both? What do you get if you echo inet_ntop($binip);

Comment: "it returns blank" Well `echo` echos; it does not "return" anything. And what is "blank"? Do `var_dump($binip)` and find out what the variable really contains: an empty string? `FALSE`? `NULL`? I'm also not sure what you're expecting to see, since `inet_pton` [does not give you a human-readable string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php). Perhaps you meant `ip2long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. I get a binary structure from your example code (although, there's no printable characters in it so if you run it in a web browser you'll probably get nothing).

Actually, I even tried this code which outputs the original address and shows that there's no information loss going on:

```
<?php
$ipaddress = '10.0.1.4';
$binip = inet_pton($ipaddress);
echo inet_ntop($binip);
?>
```

Maybe you are more interested in [ip2long](http://php.net/ip2long) which converts the address to an integer? Or maybe your problem is elsewhere, for example in escaping the data before putting it into a database?

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was a MySql issue then. I changed from binary to varbinary. Didn't think about non printable characters. Thanks!

Comment: A change from binary to varbinary shouldn't solve the problem unless the binary was the wrong size. Make sure the field have a length of 4 to make room for the entire address, no more, no less.

Comment: On further reading in the manual, they actually say that versions of MySQL <5.0.15 could change the value (stripping trailing spaces) when selecting from BINARY fields (but not in VARBINARY), so my last comment may be wrong if you have an old version.

Answer (score 0):

You have similar issues here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php

You can find out solutions from there too. Check out how that function returns FALSE.